# DBeaver : Get dynamic path from script with SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, scripting, sqlplus, dbeaver

I'm facing a problem with SQL*Plus and dynamic script path in DBeaver.

I'm using a script that calls another script *for DDL (create, alter, drop, comment, grant, etc) operations*. The first script spools into a log file in the \Logs sub-folder, and refers to a 2nd SQL file in the \Scripts sub-folder which contains all the DDL commands.

The 1st script :

```
UNDEFINE FILENAME_log;
DEFINE   FILENAME_log = 'TABLE_NAME' --Change with the TABLE_NAME
 
spool Logs\Log_&FILENAME_log..txt APPEND;
PROMPT "############# START SCRIPT #############";
-- Timestamp at start
SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as "Timestamp" FROM dual;
-- Schema where the script is executed
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') as "Schema" FROM dual;
-- Service name (DEV/PROD)
SELECT SERVICE_NAME as "Service Name" FROM gv$session WHERE sid in (SELECT sid FROM V$MYSTAT);
-- User
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT('userenv', 'os_user') as "OS_User" FROM dual;


PROMPT "///// 01_FULL_&&FILENAME_log /////";
@Scripts\01_FULL.sql;


PROMPT "############# END SCRIPT   #############";
PROMPT "";
spool off;
```

In DBeaver, I use "Execute in SQL Plus" (when connected, right click on connection > Tools > "Execute in SQL Plus").
I downloaded SQL*Plus from Oracle and referring to the executable path in the DBeaver Local Client (C:\instantclient_19_12).

Then I get the script from another folder (C:\test script) (Input)[Execute Script windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gO86.png), but when I try to spool or get the 2nd script I've an error.

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "Scripts\01_FULL.sql"
```

**Working path is** 'C:\instantclient_19_12' **when I'm expecting** 'C:\test script'.

I tried these http://orasql.org/2015/06/26/sqlplus-tips-7-how-to-find-current-script-directory/ and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17347/sqlplus-and-relative-paths but both scripts return me null for path...

**Any ideas to solve this issue ?**

PS : In SQL Developer I've used the following custom default path to look for script (Preferences > Database > Worksheet), scripts are working well.

```
"${file.dir}"
```

Comment: use absolute path rather than relative path.

Comment: Yes but that's not what I want (too much path to check/modify, not dynamic, etc).

The other option I'm working on, is to use SQL*Plus cmdline. I will update if I find a workaround.